# How can I fix bad substitution error inside docker-compose file?

Tags: bash, docker-compose

How to run a /bin/bash for loop inside docker-compose file?
It's saying bad substitution error, and I'm not sure if there is another character to escape.

```
environment:
      domains: (x.com,y.com)

entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/_internal/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf"        echo $$email
        curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem"
        ls -la /etc/letsencrypt/
        echo $$domains
        for domain in $${domains[@]}; do
          echo $$domain
        done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please include enough of your `docker-compose.yaml` for us to actually reproduce the problem. I think I know what the problem is, but because your question doesn't show what image you're using it's just an educated guess.

Your `entrypoint` script is using Bash-specific features (specifically, arrays). While on many Linux distributions, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, this isn't universally true. On Debian-derived distributions, including Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a more traditional Bourne-shell implementation without the extra features available in Bash.

If use `fedora:38` in your `docker-compose.yaml`, in which `/bin/sh` is actually Bash, it runs without errors (although it doesn't perform as you intend); the output of the loop is:

```
example_1  | (x.com,y.com)
```

On the other hand, if I use `ubuntu:22.04`, I get the error you've described in your question:

```
example_1  | /bin/sh: 5: Bad substitution
```

---

To get things working, we first need to deal with logic error -- as we saw above, when using Bash, the script runs without an error, but it doesn't actually treat your `domains` variable as an array.

There are two problems: first, Bash array syntax uses whitespace, rather than commas, to separate items; and second, you can't treat an environment variable as an array in any case. But that's okay, because we don't need an array variable at all! If we write the `docker-compose.yaml` file like this:

```
services:
  example:
    image: ubuntu:22.04
    environment:
      domains: "x.com y.com"
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        for domain in $$domains; do
          echo $$domain
        done
```

Then the output is:

```
x.com
y.com
```

Which is what we want. This doesn't require any bash-specific syntax, which means you can safely use `/bin/sh` regardless of what distribution you're using.

Comment: the image is nginx, probably alpine based. thanks a lot. this should work.